# A gambler who is equally likely to either win or lose one unit

Tags: probability

A gambler who is equally likely to either win or lose one unit on each gamble will be down n before
being up 1 with probability 1/(n + 1); or equivalently,

P(gambler is up 1 before being down n) =
$\frac{n}{n + 1}$

I don't understand how the probability is equal to $\frac{n}{n+1}$

Answer (score 1):

This exactly gambler's ruin where player 1 starts with $n$ coins, player 2 starts with $1$ coin and we ask what is the probability that player 1 wins.
The probability of that is exactly $\frac{n}{n+1}$.

Define $A_i$ to be the probability that player 1 wins when he starts with $i$ coins and player 2 starts with $n+1-i$ coins.
Check what happens at the first toss and derive a recurrence relation.